# How to create a sub NSArray that includes key-value pairs?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have the following NsArray and I want to sort it and create a sub array that include specific key-value pairs.

```
{
scores =     (
            {
        category = 2;
        "league_code" = epl;
        "team_away" = Everton;
        "team_home" = Liverpool;
    },
            {
        category = 2;
        "league_code" = epl;
        "team_away" = Fulham;
        "team_home" = "Swansea City";
    },
             {
    category = 3;
     "league_code" = ita;
    "team_away" = Torino;
    "team_home" = Milan;
},
    {
    category = 3;
     "league_code" = ita;
    "team_away" = Lazio;
    "team_home" = Juve;
}
```

}
}

and I would like to create a new array or just modify array to include only objects with "league_code" = epl key.

So I want to get

```
    {
scores =     (
            {
        category = 2;
        "league_code" = epl;
        "team_away" = Everton;
        "team_home" = Liverpool;
    },
            {
        category = 2;
        "league_code" = epl;
        "team_away" = Fulham;
        "team_home" = "Swansea City";
    }
```

}
}

I tried to convert it to use dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys but it didn't work.

Comment: Learn to read NSLog output.  That's an NSDictionary that contains an NSArray containing NSDictionary objects.

Comment: I read the NSLog but it was to confusing and I am getting my data from json.

Comment: When you parse JSON it ends up in NSArrays and NSDictionarys.  In JSON an array is surrounded by `[]`, in an NSLog dump an NSArray is surrounded by `()`.  Both JSON "objects" and their corresponding NSDictionarys are surrounded by `{}` chars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray* newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray* oldArray = outerDictionary[@"scores"];
for (NSDictionary* dictEntry in oldArray) {
    NSString* leagueCode = dictEntry[@"league_code"];
    if ([leagueCode isEqualToString @"epl"]) {
        [newArray addObject:dictEntry];
    }
}
```

Was that all that hard?

Answer (score 0):

Loop Through and the if it matches your conditions add it to a dictionary. I recommend the for-loop but any loop while do.